# Computing the metric in the barred frame using a 2D coordinate transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I would like to apply the coordinate transformation $x^{\bar{1}} = 2x^1$, $x^{\bar{2}} = x^2$ in the 2D Cartesian plane. The metric in the barred frame is $g_{\overline{ij}} = \Lambda^i_{\bar{i}} \Lambda^j_{\bar{j}} g_{ij}$, where $\Lambda^i_{\bar{i}}$ is a 2 x 2 inverse transformation matrix, and $g_{ij}$ appears to be the identity matrix:

$$g_{\overline{ij}} = \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \Lambda^j_{\bar{j}} \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

My problem is that I have no idea what $\Lambda^j_{\bar{j}}$ represents. The text I am learning from is [The Standard Model in a Nutshell](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/11050.html). Any guidance you can offer in obtaining $g_{\overline{ij}}$ will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a rank-2 tensor (like the metric) and a general coordinate transformation $x\to \bar x(x)$ you have the transformation law:
$$g_{ij}\to g_{\overline{ij}}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\bar i}}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{\bar j}}g_{ij}$$
In your case you have $g_{ij}=g^{ij}=\mathrm{diag}(1, 1)$, as you indicated. You also know exactly how each coordinate transforms so you should have no problem in calculating $g_{\overline{ij}}$ now.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've edited my question to be more clear with respect to the missing transformation matrix. And I apologize for being somewhat dense ... I have not played around with inertial reference frames and coordinate transformations since [Lorentz boosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Physical_formulation_of_Lorentz_boosts). I'm just not used to thinking about them in this way...